# Change Facebook sdk language in ember

Tags: ember.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a multilingual ember application in which i've included the facebook sdk (async):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

When the user change the application's language, i would like to change the fb sdk language as well and reparse every fb tag to get everything translated;

I've made a function to set the js.src attribute properly, but the sdk is loaded only when the page refresh, and it happens only on the first load.
How can i reload the sdk with the properly js.src attribute in ember at runtime?